# How to implement this circuit either using Jupiter notbook or qiskit

Tags: qiskit, entanglement, quantum-circuit

I am new to quantum-computaions and learning qiskit.

I am trying to construct a two qubits circuit that performs a bell measurement using $\{|\beta_{01}\rangle \langle \beta_{01}| \} $  projectors.
Circuit should be composed of unitaries and end with Z measurements.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get us to do your homework.  What have you tried?  Why is or isn't it working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.